# Entity Framework 6 - Call a method on removing an entity from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity of a physical file location:

```
public class MyFile
{
    public MyFile() { }    
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string URI { get; set; }

    DisposeFile()
    {
        //Remove physicall file here...
    }
}
```

I want the `DisposeFile()` method to be called when I remove `MyFile` entity from the database:

```
DbContext.MyFile.Remove(someMyFileEntity);
DbContext.SaveChanges(); // Call DisposeFile()
```

Is there a simple way to do so? Or should I dispose this physical file in other way?

Comment: As @ChrisBint says. Create a server layer. Ideally, I would create layers from Controller to Database like: Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Database. Where Repository will do the basic Get, Insert, Update and Delete. The service would be responsible for call methods such as DisposeFile().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you are looking for by overriding the `SaveChanges` method of your `DbContext` class:

```
public override int SaveChanges()   
{   
    var deletedMyFileEntityList = ChangeTracker.Entries()   
        .Where(f => f.Entity is MyFile && f.State == EntityState.Deleted);   

    foreach (var entity in deletedMyFileEntityList)   
    {
        try {
            entity.DisposeFile();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Here you can decide what to do if the DisposeFile method fails
        }
    }   

    return base.SaveChanges();   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, this kind of method would go into a 'Service', which you would then call a method on this service to do both delete from the context, and deleting the physical file.

Comment: Yes, I see that adding another layer of abstraction would solve the problem (and is most probably the right way to go), but my question is about forcing entity framework itself to do the job , without creating a repository or service. Thanks for your guidance, though!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ChrisBint that this kind of operations should be placed into a service, but you can take a look a this project.

[EF Hooks](https://github.com/visoft/EFHooks)

**Taken from their page:**

EFHooks is a framework to assist in hooking into the Entity Framework Code First before and after insert, update and delete actions are performed on the database.

EFHooks is designed to lend itself to code that is easy to unit test with the least amount of mocking possible and without cluttering up your DbContext class with hooking code. It also is designed to play well with IoC containers.

Getting Started:

Define a hook to fire before an action by deriving from one of the strongly typed hook classes: `PreInsertHook<TEntity>`, `PreUpdateHook<TEntity>` or `PreDeleteHook<TEntity>` and override the Hook method. (There are also Post-Action hooks)

The example below will automatically set the CreatedAt property to DateTime.Now

```
public class TimestampPreInsertHook : PreInsertHook<ITimeStamped>
{
    public override void Hook(ITimeStamped entity, HookEntityMetadata metadata)
    {
        entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Then derive your `DbContext` from the `EFHooks.HookedDbContext` and register the hooks.

```
public class AppContext : HookedDbContext
{
    public AppContext() : base()
    {
        this.RegisterHook(new TimestampPreInsertHook());
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

New up the `AppContext` and your hooks are in place and will fire when you call `SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by overriding the savechanges method in EF.

```
 var db = new RBSYNERGYEntities();

 tblProductMaster master = db.tblProductMasters.FirstOrDefault();

 db.tblProductMasters.Remove(master);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

and in model.Context.cs

```
public partial class RBSYNERGYEntities : DbContext
    {
        //Other is ommited 
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var changedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries();
            foreach (var changedEntity in changedEntities)
            {
                if (changedEntity.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    tblProductMaster info = changedEntity.Entity as tblProductMaster;
                    if (info != null)
                    {
                        //Do your work here
                        int a = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```